# Returning table in Postgres without defining its structure

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `foo` and a procedure `bar`.

`bar` filters data from `foo` into a temporary table `footemp` whose structure is same as that of `foo`.

Finally it returns query `select * from footemp`

I don't want to redefine the structure of the return table in the function definition.

Is there a way to tell Postgres that the function returns a table whose structure is similar to `foo`?

Note: I know that `footemp` can be created using `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ...` this question is about not having to define the structure of the return table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create function bar() returns setof foo
```

Comment: Does it have any performance / memory footprint penalty as compared to defining the table structure after `RETURNS`?